# How insert a shape (textbox) into an Excel with ClosedXML?

Tags: excel, office-interop, closedxml

How can I insert a shape (textbox) into an Excel Worksheet with ClosedXML?

Or, what free libray can I use to make Excel files?

I'm using interop, but with Win10 I have compability problems with Excel 365 x64, because I have other lib's and my soft is exclusive for x86.

Comment: What have you tried?  What error message or undesirable behavior did you encounter?

Comment: This is part of why Microsoft still recommends installing the x86 version of Office, even on 64bit machines and operating systems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert shape in Worksheet with ClosedXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140949/insert-shape-in-worksheet-with-closedxml)